# React: Creating different user profiles

Tags: database, reactjs, firebase, authentication

I'm making an app in React and I want to users have the option to create an account using their email/password as auth factors. However, I want the option for two different user types. For example, a client and physician. So that when a user logs in they are taken to unique profiles (ie: clientProfile.js or physicianProfile.js) to that user type. Is this a db item? A firebase Auth token? Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1):

1. When a user registers they'll select their `role` from a `select` dropdown (or whatever UI element you choose): **Client** *or* **Physician**. You'll save this to the database.
2. When the user logs in you'll return their `role` along with any other relevant user data the front-end needs to handle the user.
3. When you render the profile you'll check their `role` and return the appropriate component: `clientProfile.js` *or* `physicianProfile.js`

Your component may look something like this:

```
class UserProfile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        /* fetch user from database */
        this.setState({user: response.user});
    }
    render() {
        const { user } = this.state;

        if (user === null) {
            return <Loading/>;
        }
        if (user.role === 'physician') {
            return <PhysicianProfile user={user}/>;
        }
        return <ClientProfile user={user}/>;
    }
}
```